# Retrofit, parsing JSON null exception at response

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit in my app. I've got JSON response which looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "list": [
      {
        "id": 58,
        "beacon_id": "58",
        "bridge_id": null,
        "mesh_id": null,
        "name": "eon_3c",
        "location": "abcdlk",
        "mac_address": "3c:cf:82:8a:e7:fe",
        "firmware": "2.1",
        "pcb_revision": "2.0",
        "battery_level": "99",
        "password": "0000",
        "ib": {
          "turn_on": "1",
          "major": "33",
          "minor": "344",
          "tx_power": "7",
          "interval": "400",
          "uuid": "dae19960-18ea-11e5-8ff0-0002a5d5c521",
          "secure_uuid": "0"
        },
        "euid": {
          "turn_on": "0",
          "namespace": null,
          "instance": null,
          "tx_power": null,
          "interval": null
        },
        "eeid": {
          "turn_on": "0",
          "tx_power": null,
          "interval": null
        },
        "eurl": {
          "turn_on": "0",
          "tx_power": null,
          "interval": null,
          "url": null
        },
        "etlm": {
          "turn_on": "0",
          "tx_power": null,
          "interval": null
        },
        "assigned_bridge_id": null
      },
      {
        "id": 56,
        "beacon_id": "56",
        "bridge_id": null,
        "mesh_id": null,
        "name": "Eon_e6",
        "location": "test",
        "mac_address": "e6:f5:8a:94:b8:c7",
        "firmware": "2.1",
        "pcb_revision": "2.0",
        "battery_level": null,
        "password": "0000",
        "ib": {
          "turn_on": "1",
          "major": "2591",
          "minor": "0",
          "tx_power": "10",
          "interval": "2593",
          "uuid": "dae19960-18ea-11e5-8ff0-0002a5d5c521",
          "secure_uuid": "0"
        },
        "euid": {
          "turn_on": "0",
          "namespace": null,
          "instance": null,
          "tx_power": null,
          "interval": null
        },
        "eeid": {
          "turn_on": "0",
          "tx_power": null,
          "interval": null
        },
        "eurl": {
          "turn_on": "0",
          "tx_power": null,
          "interval": null,
          "url": null
        },
        "etlm": {
          "turn_on": "0",
          "tx_power": null,
          "interval": null
        },
        "assigned_bridge_id": null
      },
      {
        "id": 57,
        "beacon_id": "57",
        "bridge_id": "13",
        "mesh_id": "278",
        "name": "Marta B",
        "location": "lk",
        "mac_address": "e1:4b:64:c3:80:e2",
        "firmware": "2.1",
        "pcb_revision": "2.0",
        "battery_level": "97",
        "password": "0000",
        "ib": {
          "turn_on": "1",
          "major": "325",
          "minor": "10",
          "tx_power": "8",
          "interval": "610",
          "uuid": "dae19960-18ea-11e5-8ff0-0002a5d5c521",
          "secure_uuid": "0"
        },
        "euid": {
          "turn_on": "0",
          "namespace": null,
          "instance": null,
          "tx_power": null,
          "interval": null
        },
        "eeid": {
          "turn_on": "0",
          "tx_power": null,
          "interval": null
        },
        "eurl": {
          "turn_on": "0",
          "tx_power": null,
          "interval": null,
          "url": null
        },
        "etlm": {
          "turn_on": "0",
          "tx_power": null,
          "interval": null
        },
        "assigned_bridge_id": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "ver": 1,
  "time": 1475671202,
  "status": 1,
  "status_msg": ""
}
```

Here's my response class:

```
public class BeaconResponse {
    @Expose
    public Data data;
    @Expose
    public int ver;
    @Expose
    public int time;
    @Expose
    public int status;
    @Expose
    public String statusMsg;
}
```

In the `Data` class I've got `List` with `List` objects. I know it's bad naming, sorry.

```
public class Data extends Model {
    @Column
    public java.util.List<List> list;
}
```

And here's my `List.class`:

```
public class List {

    public Integer id;
    public String beaconId;
    public String bridgeId;
    public String meshId;
    public String name;
    public String location;
    public String macAddress;
    public String firmware;
    public String pcbRevision;
    public String batteryLevel;
    public String password;
    public Ib ib;
    public Euid euid;
    public Eeid eeid;
    public Eurl eurl;
    public Etlm etlm;
    public int assignedBridgeId;
}
```

I think it should work, but it doesn't. When I try to map it to the model class I'm getting 3 objects `ResponseList.size = 3`  but all fields are `null`: `data`, `statusMSG` and so on. Can you tell me why this is? Thanks in advance for helping :)

My interface :

```
@GET("/api/mobile/{language}/{apiVersion}/beacons/list")
void beaconsList(Callback<BasicResponse<BeaconsListResponse>> callback);

public class BeaconsListResponse {
    @Expose
    public List<BeaconResponse> list;
}
```

Here's my retrofit call:

```
@Subscribe
public void getUserBeacons(GetBeaconsListCommand command) {
    Callback<BasicResponse<BeaconsListResponse>> callback = new Callback<BasicResponse<BeaconsListResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(BasicResponse<BeaconsListResponse> basicResponse, Response response) {
            if (ResponseStatus.SUCCESS.statusCode == basicResponse.status)
                EventBus.post(new BeaconsListFetchedEvent(basicResponse.data));
            else
                EventBus.post(new NetworkFailureEvent(ResponseStatus.getByStatus(basicResponse.status), basicResponse.status_msg));
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        }
    };
    service.beaconsList(callback);
}
```

Main response class:

```
public class BasicResponse<T> {
    @Expose
    public T list;
    @Expose
    public int ver;
    @Expose
    public long time;
    @Expose
    public byte status;
    @Expose
    public String status_msg;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your retrofit call

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: What is Basicresponse for?

Comment: Main response class - added to the post

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should create your response class like this:

```
@SerializedName("list")
@Expose
private List<Data> list = new ArrayList<Data>();
```

Try creating your Response class through this tool:

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your Java classes do not mimic your JSON schema. You Java classes need to match the JSON schema *exactly*, or GSON will not be able to deserialize the data. This should better represent your schema:

```
public class StandardResponse<T> {

    @SerializedName("data") public T data;
    @SerializedName("ver") public Integer version;
    @SerializedName("time") public Long time;
    @SerializedName("status") public Integer status;
    @SerializedName("status_msg") public String statusMessage;

}
```

Then you can implement a `ListData` class that contains a `List`:

```
public class ListData<T> {

    @SerializedName("list") public List<T> list;

}
```

Then on to your `Beacon` class:

```
public class Beacon {

    @SerializedName("id") public Integer id;
    @SerializedName("beacon_id") public String beaconID;
    @SerializedName("bridge_id") public String bridgeID;
    @SerializedName("mesh_id") public String meshID;
    @SerializedName("name") public String name;
    @SerializedName("location") public String location;
    @SerializedName("mac_address") public String macAddress;
    @SerializedName("firmware") public String firmware;
    @SerializedName("pcb_revision") public String pcbRevision;
    @SerializedName("battery_level") public String batteryLevel;
    @SerializedName("password") public String password;
    @SerializedName("ib") public Ib ib;
    @SerializedName("euid") public Euid euid;
    @SerializedName("eeid") public Eeid eeid;
    @SerializedName("eurl") public Eurl eurl;
    @SerializedName("etlm") public Etlm etlm;
    @SerializedName("assigned_bridge_id") public String assignedBridgeID;

}
```

I will skip your `Ib`, `Euid`, `Edid`, `Eurl` and `Etlm` classes, as they should not be too difficult to implement based on the classes above.

---

With these classes, your Retrofit `Callback` should look like this:

```
@GET("/api/mobile/{language}/{apiVersion}/beacons/list")
void getBeacons(Callback<StandardResponse<ListData<Beacon>> callback);
```

And finally, you can obtain your list of `Beacon` objects from the callback like so:

```
service.getBeacons(new Callback<StandardResponse<ListData<Beacon>>> {

    @Override
    public void success(StandardResponse<ListData<Beacon>> standard, Response response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Status: " + standard.status + "; with message: " + standard.statusMessage);
        List<Beacon> beacons = standard.data.list;

        for(Beacon beacon: beacons) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Beacon ID: " + beacon.id);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        // TODO: implement error handling
    }

});
```

Based on your sample JSON, the above code should print the following in logcat:

```
Status: 1, with message:
Beacon ID: 58
Beacon ID: 56
Beacon ID: 57
```

---

**Update**

Here are the `Ib`, `Euid`, `Edid`, `Eurl` and `Etlm` classes:

```
public class Ib {

    @SerializedName("turn_on") public String turnOn;
    @SerializedName("major") public String major;
    @SerializedName("minor") public String minor;
    @SerializedName("tx_power") public String txPower;
    @SerializedName("interval") public String interval;
    @SerializedName("uuid") public String uuid;
    @SerializedName("secure_uuid") public String uuidSecure;

}

public class Euid {

    @SerializedName("turn_on") public String turnOn;
    @SerializedName("namespace") public String nameSpace;
    @SerializedName("instance") public String instance;
    @SerializedName("tx_power") public String txPower;
    @SerializedName("interval") public String interval;

}

public class Edid {

    @SerializedName("turn_on") public String turnOn;
    @SerializedName("tx_power") public String txPower;
    @SerializedName("interval") public String interval;

}

public class Eurl {

    @SerializedName("turn_on") public String turnOn;
    @SerializedName("tx_power") public String txPower;
    @SerializedName("interval") public String interval;
    @SerializedName("url") public String url;

}

public class Etlm {

    @SerializedName("turn_on") public String turnOn;
    @SerializedName("tx_power") public String txPower;
    @SerializedName("interval") public String interval;

}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work :/ Everything is parsed ok , but Ib, Euid, Edid, Eurl and Etlm are null :/

Comment: @Bartos But everything else parsed as expected? Maybe you didn't create those classes correctly? I will update with a representation of those classes.

Comment: Everything is parsed ok except objects :/ I created classes as you said. When I debug app I've got this exception while creating EonBeaconModel Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate pl.netizens.eonbeacon.storage.EonBeaconModel.toString()

Comment: @Bartos What is the `EonBeaconModel` class?